# How can I find a right-inverse of a fat matrix over $\Bbb F_2$?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, finite-fields, inverse

Suppose I have a full rank fat binary matrix $A \in \{0,1\}^{m\times n}$ with $m<n$. How can I find a matrix $A^{\dagger}$ such that $AA^{\dagger}=I_{m}$?

The traditional method used for matrices over $\Bbb R$, which yields

$$A^{\dagger} = A^T \left( A A^T \right)^{-1},$$

does not work in general because, even with full rank $A$, $AA^T$ may be not invertible. For example, if $A=\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 1 \end{bmatrix}$, then $A A^T = 1 + 1 = 0$, which is not invertible.

Comment: You should be able to solve this in the special case there $A$ is a (non-square) diagonal matrix.  To generalize this approach, use the Rank Normal Form of A.

Comment: Why are you inverting matrices instead of using Gaussian elimination?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using row operations and column operations,
you can always make $A$ into the form $D=[I_m|O_{n-m}]$.
In other words,
there exist invertible $P$ and $Q$ of suitable sizes such that
$A=PDQ$.
Then $A^\dagger=Q^{-1}D^\top P^{-1}$.
In fact, this works over any field.